# Every continuous function from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$ is a quotient map

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

A continuous surjection $f:X\to Y$ is a [quotient map](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotient_space_(topology)#Quotient_map) if the topology on $Y$ is the final topology with respect to $f$, namely, for each subset $F\subset Y$, $F$ is closed if $f^{-1}(F)$ is closed in $X$.

Equivalently, for each saturated closed subset $B$ of $X$, $f(B)$ is closed in $Y$.  (Here, saturated = saturated with respect to $f$, i.e., saturated with respect to the fibers $f^{-1}(y)$.)

All the examples of a map that is not quotient that I could find in various references or on this site were always a little complicated.  So I tried to find a simple example of a continuous map from the reals to the reals that is not a quotient map.  After a while I realized it is not possible:

> Every continuous map $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ is a quotient map, when viewed a surjection onto its image.

Apart from checking that my reasoning below is correct, can you provide a different proof?  Specifically, is this a consequence of some more general topological results?

---

*Proof of result:*
Let $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$ and $f$ be a continuous map from $X$ to $Y$.
Let $B$ be a saturated closed set in $X$.  We have to show that $f(B)$ is closed in $f(X)$.  Suppose that is not the case.  So we can find $a\in X$ with $f(a)\notin f(B)$, but such that $f(a)$ is a limit point of $f(B)$.  There is a sequence $(x_n)$ in $B$ such that $f(x_n)$ converges to $f(a)$.  Taking a subsequence if necessary, we can assume that $f(x_n)$ converges monotonically to $f(a)$.  Without loss of generality, say it's an increasing sequence, and $a<x_1$.

We have $f(x_1)<f(x_n)<f(a)$, so by the intermediate value theorem there is a $z_n\in[a,x_1]$ such that $f(z_n)=f(x_n)$.  Since $B$ is saturated, the point $z_n$ also belongs to $B$.  Thus $(z_n)$ is a bounded sequence in $B$ and by compactness there is a subsequence converging to a point $z\in B$ (because $B$ is closed).  Replacing $(z_n)$ again by that subsequence, we can assume $z_n$ converges to $z$, and by continuity of $f$ we have $f(z_n)$ converging to $f(z)$.  But that is the same as $f(x_n)$, which converges to $f(a)$.  So $f(a)=f(z)$ did belong to $f(B)$ after all.